# This code gives an abort trap 6 when the array elements is odd.eg z[3] gives abort error 6 but z[4] doesn't works just fine. Also I use MacBook Pro

Tags: c, compiler-errors

when the array elements is odd.eg z[3] gives abort error 6 but z[4] doesn't works just fine. Also I use MacBook Pro
and I meant the size of the array. whenever its even it works and whenever its odd it doesn't. as simple as that.ps using normal words.

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main(){
    long int x,y,z[3];
    printf("The size of %lu\n",sizeof(z[x]));
    for(x=1;x<=3;x++){
        printf("Number %lu \n",x);
        scanf("%lu",&z[x]);
 }
     size_t n = sizeof(z);
     printf("The size of %lu\n",n);
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `z[3]` and `z[4]` are both out of bounds accesses resulting in undefined behaviour. Array indicies in C start from 0 so value indices for `z` are `0,1,2`.

Comment: And before you say "but but z[4] works" please understand that undefined behaviour means that the result is unpredictable (including sometimes appearing to  "work").

Comment: It's not quite clear in the question but if by "`z[4]` works fine" you mean you defined the variable as `long int z[4]` then that's OK: you can index it by `3`. But you can't legally index the variable `long int z[3]` by `3`.

Comment: @kaylum `z[3]` or `z[4]` are the variable definition: the indexing is with `z[x]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think you're right. I misunderstood that as the title says "array **element**".

Comment: @kaylum your advice is still good though. Perhaps OP can frame questions better in the future.

Comment: I meant the size of the array. whenever its even it works and whenever its odd it doesn't. as simple as that.ps using normal words.

Comment: Your `printf("The size of %lu\n",sizeof(z[x]));` line is using an **unitialized** variable (`x`). It could be that your compiler is arranging memory in such a way that, when you declare an even-sized array, `x` is getting a value of zero but, for odd-sized arrays, it's getting a *daft* value (out-of-bounds). Try adding an explicit initializer for `x`, like; `long int x=0, y, z[3];`

Comment: … that should be **uninitialized** of course (coffee not working yet).

Comment: Actually I was just curious about how this could be possible cause this program works very differently with the odd and even integers.I wanted to know the reason but no one seem to help.